# how to paste in Design View in Dreamweaver CS4 when in code view

Tags: view, dreamweaver, paste

When i'm working in code view, I press Ctrl+tilda to switch to Design view and then do  Ctrl-V.
How to do it from within Code View only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver pastes only in the view that has focus. If you want to paste into Design View you have to focus in Design View.